# Select and fill face in UV Editor using Fill brush

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor

Is there any way to select a specific face / island in the UV / Image Editor while in Paint Mode? I'm not talking about Texture Paint mode in the 3D view, rather, the Paint mode in UV / Image Editor mode.

What I actually want to do is to select one of those faces and use the "Fill" brush, so it doesn't fill the whole image, but only the selected face / island.

I can freely paint and fill the image, but I can't select specific faces to fill. Is it even possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not at the moment a way to do this without using the 3d view. You can use the edit mode in the 3d view and the UV Image Editor to make a selection, and then switch to texture paint mode in the 3d view with Face Select Masking turned on, Fill tool there in the 3d view and see the update in the UV Image Editor.

Comment: I see. That's a bit unfortunate, that there's no way to do it without using the 3D View. But your answer works. Thanks a lot!